# Using an if statement to replace NA values in a column

Tags: r

So I am trying to fill a column Name from an existing character string. Most of the character strings look like this:

```
;Parties;John, Smith;Defendant;
```

And so I've been able to extract names using this code

```
data$name <- str_to_upper(str_extract(data$column, "(?<=;Parties;)(\\D){4,60}(?=;Defendant)"))
```

However, there are a few NA values in my name column

```
name
JOHN, SMITH
JANE, DOE
BOB, ROSS
NA

sum(is.na(data$name)) 
[1] 888
```

When I look at these NA rows with data$column[4], it looks like this:

```
Agency;Michael, Scott;Defendant
```

I'm trying to fill the NAs in the name column. Here is my code:

```
data$name <- if(is.na(data$name)) {
str_to_upper(str_extract(data$column, "(?<=Agency;)(\\D){4,60}(?=;Defendant)"))
}
```

But I get this error:

```
In if (is.na(data$name)) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: try using the ifelse function, something like data$name <- ifelse(is.na(data$name),  str_to_upper(str_extract(data$column, "(?<=Agency;)(\\D){4,60}(?=;Defendant)"))
, str_to_upper(str_extract(data$column, "(?<=;Parties;)(\\D){4,60}(?=;Defendant)")) )
}

Comment: is.na(data$name) will return a column of booleans representing if NA or not. So you need to do this check in a loop.

Comment: `isna <- is.na(data$column); data$column[isna] <- str_to_upper(str_extract(data$column[isna], "(?<=Agency;)(\\D){4,60}(?=;Defendant)"));`

Comment: This is perfect!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is fully based on the comment by @r2evans, but I think it is good to mark questions as solved to leave them closed.

```
isna <- is.na(data$column)
data$column[isna] <- str_to_upper(
                       str_extract(data$column[isna], 
                                   "(?<=Agency;)(\\D){4,60}(?=;Defendant)"))
```